# How to store data with a deployed app and deployed functions on firebase

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase

I have this angular code to get the datas

```
$http({
    header: 'content-type:application/json',
    method:'GET',
    url: 'https://us-central1-****-*****.cloudfunctions.net/**/GetAll****',
  }).then(function(messages){
    $scope.member = messages.data.****
  })
```

the error in the console is

```
Failed to load https://us-central1-site-*****.cloudfunctions.net/**/GetAll****: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://site-******.firebaseapp.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Please could anyone help me

Answer (score 2):

Just add these lines before sending the response in your cloud function, as you need to enable **CORS**:

```
function foo(req, res) {  
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token'); // <-- Try adding this line
  res.status(200).send('custom message');
}
```

Comment: you mean the name of express app by "res" ?

Comment: Yeah, by `res` I mean the res object in an express app. I've updated my answer to provide more context on where to use the headers.

Comment: In the request of POST this error : Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Comment: I've added a third header, can you add it and try again?

Comment: same problem nothing changed in the console

Comment: It seems to be an [outage](https://status.firebase.google.com/), not sure if that could affect in some way that changes aren't reflected

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but when i was trying. Normally this error happens because of when you try to access "http" to "https" so the browser blocks for security reasons. What you have to do is, use cors like below

Step 1 : first install cors with npm in the firebase functions.

Step 2 : After installing the cors, write your function in the following way

```
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true }); // origin true must be there
exports.sampleFunction = functions.https.onRequest((request, response)=>{
   cors(request,response, () =>{
       // Do your business logic or code.
   })
})
```

[image: My Firebase functions. See the highlighted code]

[image: Reply from firebase support team when i had the same issue]

Comment: Did my answer helped you? If it's please kindly consider upvoting the answer